# enum in dropdown using best_in_place and activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, activeadmin, best-in-place

I am using best_in_place with active admin. And I can seem to get it to work in case of a dropdown of enums.

The enums in use are :

```
enum day: [MONDAY.to_s, TUESDAY.to_s, WEDNESDAY.to_s, THURSDAY.to_s, FRIDAY.to_s, SATURDAY.to_s, SUNDAY.to_s]
```

each of the constants are just like :

```
MONDAY = "monday"
```

Im trying to use best_in_place on the columns :

```
column :day do |d|
  best_in_place d, :day, as: :select, url: [:admin,d], collection: Order.days.enum_for(:each_with_index).collect{|k,index| [k[0], index]}
end
```

This shows a list of 0, 1, 2, but works as expected.

I have tried variations like :

```
Order.days
Order.days.keys
```

Order.days.keys gives a list of the days. But it does not pick up the already set one. eg. tuesday has been set previously, it shows it as empty. And does not set it either.

I want the dropdown to work with the list of names of the days. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with your exact setup, but doing the following helped to allow enum-driven select collections in my project using best_in_place:

```
best_in_place host, :platform, as: :select, collection: Host.platforms.keys.map { |w| [w, w] }
```

This sets the select value and dropdown item as identical. Or if you want to make it more readable you can do:

```
Host.platforms.keys.map { |w| [w, w.humanize] }
```

Hopefully that gets you somewhere!